# Crawling to get specific content from another website

Tags: php, web-crawler

i have a search box .... i want to enter a certain value in the box .....i have urls of some websites, on which required  data is available.For example

`http://www.zafa.com.pk/tablets.html ,  http://www.zafa.com.pk/injections.html`

When I click on search button then the script should return only those websites URL whose content matches with the input searched value. Kindly let me know how can i do this
i tried following code but it didnt work for me

**Note:** I am not searching the whole website I am only searching through the certain pages of the website.

```
<?php 
  $ch = curl_init(); 
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://www.google.com'); 
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0); 
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 300);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 300);
  $data = curl_exec($ch); 
  file_put_contents("text.txt", $data);
  curl_close($ch); 
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like following:

**Note:** the following code will work for single website. For multiple webites you can use `explode()` and `foreach`

```
$searc_in = file_get_contents('http://www.zafa.com.pk/tablets.html');
$findme = 'CARDACE';
$pos = strpos($searc_in, $findme);


if ($pos === false) {
    echo "The string '$findme' was not found in the website";
} else {
    echo "The string '$findme' was found in the website";
    echo " and exists at position $pos";
}
```